# Free memory in another function

Tags: c, malloc

So I have this code in which allocation is happening in one function and deallocation is being done in the calling function. Getting Segmentation fault or Abort message while trying to free the memory either by ptr or *ptr. Kindly have a look:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    char *ptr;
    fun(&ptr);
    printf("ptr = %p\n",ptr);
    printf("&ptr = %p\n",&ptr);
    printf("String ptr = %s\n",ptr);
    free (ptr);

    return 0;
}
void fun(char **str)
{
    *str = malloc(10);
    *str = "HELLO";
    printf("str = %p\n",str);
    printf("&str = %p\n",&str);

    printf("String str = %s\n",*str);
}
```

Following is the output:

```
str = 0x7ffe63247858                                                                                                                 
&str = 0x7ffe63247838                                                                                                                
String str = HELLO                                                                                                                   
ptr = 0x400764                                                                                                                       
&ptr = 0x7ffe63247858                                                                                                                
String ptr = HELLO                                                                                                                   
*** Error in `/home/a.out': munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000000400764 ***                                                  
Aborted
```

Question :

Why can't we free ptr ? And if we can, what is the best way to do it ?

Comment: @ThiruShetty in fact this is not the problem(see the answers)

Answer (score 6):

you're overwriting the pointer value in the line after, making `*str` point to a literal.

So you have a memory leak *and* undefined behaviour by trying to `free` a literal.

You probably mean

```
strcpy(*str,"hello");
```

Note that those 2 lines could be changed into a working single line like this:

```
*str = strdup("HELLO");
```

which has the advantage of allocating the exact number of bytes for the string instead of guessing.

Comment: Thanks a lot for making it clear. Using strdup() will make the task more easier. But there should be some other way as well to do it without using strcpy() or strdup(). Like, in case we don't have access to string functions. Any idea how to achieve this ?

Comment: yes but that's a bit ludicrious because if you don't have access to string functions, you probably don't have access to `malloc` as well. I would count how many chars there's in the string, add 1, malloc the proper size, then copy byte by byte. Not editing answer with that unless there's a real setting where `malloc` is callable but not `strcpy`

Comment: also there _was_ a debate about using `strdup` or no a few years ago, but now `strdup` comes as a standard.

Answer (score 1):

When you do `*str = "HELLO";` it does not have the effect you expect. Instead of assigning value to the allocated memory, you are re-assigning the pointer to point to the string literal and thus later you try to deallocate it (thus the error). Instead of this you should use `strcpy` like `strcpy(*str, "HELLO")`.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question of how to do this without explicit string copying, instead of

```
char *p = "hello";
```

do

```
char p[] = "hello";
```

The first points p to a non-modifiable portion of memory.  The second allocates an array large enough to hold the literal and copies the literal into it.

Answer (score 0):

you are changing memory address pointed str pointer after malloc in fun. you should do strcpy instead of direct assignment :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    char *ptr;
    fun(&ptr);
    printf("ptr = %p\n",ptr);
    printf("&ptr = %p\n",&ptr);
    printf("String ptr = %s\n",ptr);
    free (ptr);

    return 0;
}
void fun(char **str)
{
    *str = malloc(10);
    strcpy(*str,"HELLO");//*str = "HELLO";
    printf("str = %p\n",str);
    printf("&str = %p\n",&str);

    printf("String str = %s\n",*str);
}
```